# optimize word by word comparison

Tags: python

I'm trying to crawl through a text and add an edge weight to a network of the words each time two words appear in the same sentence together. I'm using `networkx`. Here is my code:

```
for word in  words:
    for otherWord in words:
            for sent in sents:
                if re.search(r'\b'+word+r'\b', str1) and re.search(r'\b'+otherWord+r'\b', str1) and word != otherWord:
                     #add edge weight
```

This is very slow and becomes exponentially slower with increasing text size. Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: Any example of input and output data?

Comment: Is words your Graph?

Comment: `words` is the `list` of the `set` of words in the text

Comment: Can't you use `set` operations such as `intersection`, `difference`, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One improvement that you can implement:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(words)):
        word, other_word = words[i], words[j]
        ...
```

So instead of doing n^2 iterations, you'll be doing `n^2/2` (half).

This improvement will invalidate the need to check if `word == other_word` which is also very good because the way it's implemented in the question - a regex search will run every time even when `word == other_word` - and regex is expensive!

Comment: This is especially nice because it speeds up at the end!

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the sentences once, split each into words (removing duplicates), and then loop over all the pairs of words in that sentence; then you won't be wasting time on pairs that never appear anywhere.

Note that this can be done in conjunction with alfasin's suggestion.

Comment: set() is your friend in eliminating duplicates

Comment: Both of these suggestions are so good--can I accept them both?

Comment: @Sam: No, but alfasin's was first.